# Why cocoon in my code not capturing callbacks?

Tags: javascript, ruby, cocoon-gem, apache-cocoon

I have a functional nested form in ruby make with cocoon. The problem is that I am trying to use before-insert and after-insert and it does nothing.

My miew:

```
<div class="row" id="street_enter_itineraries">
          <table>
            <div class="street_enter_itineraries" >
              <%= f.fields_for :street_enter_itineraries do |builder| %>
                <%= render 'street_enter_itinerary_fields', f:builder %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </table>
            <div class="row">
              <%= link_to_add_association  "Añadir calle de entrada",f, :street_enter_itineraries, class: 'btn btn-info', data: {association_insertion_node: '.street_enter_itineraries', association_insertion_method: :append}  %>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#street_enter_itineraries')
        .on('cocoon:before-insert', function() {
            var allIds= document.getElementsByClassName("tipocalleentradaidentificar");
            if(allIds.length > 3){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
            refreshID();
        })
});
```

I have seen this post: [Cocoon add association, how to limit number of associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934925/cocoon-add-association-how-to-limit-number-of-associations) because of it is what I want to do. I have tried this option too, and console is empty:

```
 $(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', '.content form', function(e) {
    console.log('Something');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks? The bottom should always log something, if you would have a class `.content ` containing the form, is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery selector is wrong, you forgot the `#` at the start to signify searching for an id. So you wrote `$('street_enter_itineraries')` and you should write

```
$('#street_enter_itineraries')
```

[EDIT] Making the js turbolinks is relatively easy, either make sure it is triggered upon `turbolinks:load`, instead of using the document ready event (in your case probably the easiest)

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(e) {
    $('#street_enter_itineraries') ...
})
```

or register the cocoon handlers on the document with the correct selector:

```
$(document).on('cocoon:before-insert', '#street_enter_itineraties', function(e) {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: maybe it has lost the slash because of several attemps, but is not working although I put it

Comment: Then maybe it is a turbolinks issue? Your js code is not turbolinks-safe, it will only work on first load, and then your page might not yet contain the correct elements.

Comment: And do you know how can I make it turbolink-safe? I'm quite young in ruby and it is the first time I hear about it

Comment: I updated my answer how to make it turbolinks compliant.